# Вырезать url адрес изображения

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите регулярку, чтоб вырезать из строки url("/images/image.png"); ссылку на изображение.

Comment: Что должно получиться в результате из этой `url("/images/image.png");` строки?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734288/extract-image-path-using-javascript-regex

Comment: /images/image.png